# Django: Trying to get last field's value from another table (FK) and add to my model

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables, the relation is one to many, "Book" (id, name, author) -> "BookStatus" (id, status, date). I want to get all the books with their  LAST status (according the field 'date') in a queryset. How can I accomplish that?

After that, how could I show that field (status) through my model "Book", something like Book.last_status.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't easy to do through the ORM. The reason is that the SQL required for this is surprisingly complex. First you need to fetch the latest status date, then join the status matching that status.

If you need only access to the latest status on Python side, then you can use book.statuses.latest() (generates a query per model), or possibly a property on the model:

```
@property
def latest_status(self):
    latest_status = None
    for status in self.statuses.all():
        if latest_status is None or latest_status.date < status.date:
            latest_status = status
    return latest_Status
```

Now you can use latest_status on Python side to fetch the latest status of the book. If you add prefetch_related when fetching books, accessing latest_status will not generate a query.

If you need access to the latest status when querying things become much more complicated. I have often used a solution where I create views in to the database for latest items, then use those views through the ORM. So, something like this in the database:

```
CREATE VIEW latest_book_status_view AS (
    SELECT null AS id,
           book_status.book_id,
           book_status.id AS status_id
      FROM book_status
     WHERE book_status.date = (SELECT max(inner_status.date)
                                 FROM book_status inner_status
                                WHERE inner_status.book_id = book_status.book_id)
);
```

In models.py:

```
class LatestBookStatus(models.Model):
    # Note the null id column above. It will be used as fake primary key
    # for this model.
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='latest_status')
    status = models.OneToOneField(BookStatus, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "latest_book_status_view"
        managed = False
```

Now you should be able to issue queries where you filter on status:

```
Book.objects.filter(latest_status__status__date__gte=today())...
```

And you can fetch the latest status by:

```
qs = Book.objects.select_related('latest_status__status')
# access it
qs[0].latest_status.status.date
```

Unfortunately this setup is complex and comes with some problems. For example, when testing you will need some way to generate the views in to the testing database. Django 1.7 migrations and RunSQL operation is one way to do this.

In short: if you need access to latest status on Python side, use the property approach. If you need access to the latest status on SQL side, be prepared for a more comlex solution. One possible solution is given above.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set nice [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and setup proper [`get_latest_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.get_latest_by) for `BookStatus`.

```
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('statuses')
books[0].statuses.latest()
```

Comment: This isn't the right way to proceed, books[0].statuses.latest() will generate another query, not use the prefetched values.

Comment: @akaariai how would u do that then?