# Django first() on children_set in bulk

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a Parent:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass
```

and Child:

```
class Child(models.Model):
     models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

I'd like to get set of Parents with their first child and make it as fast as possible. Currently I do:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     def __init__(self):
         self.first_child = self.child_set.first()
```

and use parent.first_child later. But this results in one query per one init call in Parent and it's too slow. How could I optimize it? Can I .annotate() it somehow?

edit: I need to be able to filter Parents, so prefetch_related is not an option. I'm using Django 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any easy solution to this.

One possibility is to do a prefetch_related for the child_set, and then assign the first element of that into the query. Not optimal, as you need to fetch all childrens into memory for each parent. On the other hand you will not need to create a separate query for each parent object, instead just two queries is enough (one to fetch the parent instances, the other to prefetch the children instances). This might be fast enough.

Fetching all the results in a single query isn't easy to do. You can also check [Django: Trying to get last field's value from another table (FK) and add to my model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754280/django-trying-to-get-last-fields-value-from-another-table-fk-and-add-to-my-m/24755448#24755448) for a possible (but unfortunately complex) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use prefetch_related or select_related to query following relations:

**select_related**:

select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.

**prefetch_related**:

prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...
    some_fields
    ...

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

then you can fetch parents and childrens in just 2 queries:

```
parents = Parent.objects.prefetch_related('children').all()
```

Or you can fetch children with parents in just 1 query

```
children = Child.objects.select_related('parent').all()
```

You can even get the specific parents from the children:

```
children_for_specific_parent = Child.objects.select_related('parent').filter(parent=1).all()
```

Of course you could use a Manager as well:

```
class ParentManager(models.Manager):

    get_first_child(self, pk):
        """
        You can assign arguments to further filter
        your manager.
        This is a rough example, you should prefer using
        exceptions etc, but for the sake of the example i keep it simple.
        """
        if pk:
            try:
                found = self.prefetch_related('children').filter(id=pk)
                children = [p.children for p in found]
                return children[0]
            except:
                pass
        return None


class Parent(models.Model):
    objects = ParentManager()
```

Then:

```
"""
Fetch first child for parent with id=1
"""
first_child = Parent.objects.get_first_child(1)
```

Comment: Sure, but prefetch_related does not work with filter and I need filtering.

Comment: Filtering is not working if you further filter the results of your queryset...try it in a django shell and you shall see that prefetch_related uses only 2 queries...you would have problems if you did a `child.filter(something)` after the evaluation of the queryset.